# Vaadin 23 Grid only grid-cell-content counts as hitbox for selecting a row

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

The problem appears in the vaadin grid in the version Vaadin 23.3.0.
I noticed, that clicking on any part of a row does not always trigger the row-select. In marked the hitbox in the image below. Clicking anywhere in the cell will trigger the itemClickEvent, but only the content part (green area in the provided image) triggers the select.
[grid with hitbox highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUmmj.png)

```
Grid<Client> grid = new Grid<>();
grid.addColumn(Client::getName).setHeader("name");
grid.addColumn(Client::getOutput).setHeader("output");
ArrayList<Client> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Client("test 1", "output 1", null));
list.add(new Client("test 2", "output 2", null));
list.add(new Client("test 3", "output 3", null));
list.add(new Client(null, "output 4", null));
list.add(new Client("test 5", null, null));
list.add(new Client(null, null, null));
grid.setSelectionMode(Grid.SelectionMode.SINGLE);
grid.setItems(list);
```

Given the explanation in the vaadin documentation:

> In single selection mode, the user can select and deselect rows by clicking anywhere on the row.

I except this exact behaviour.
After noticing the problem, I created the grid, to which I provided code and image above, to narrow down a possible cause.

Comment: You should create an issue: https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues

Answer (score 1):

Issue was fixed with vaadin 23.3.2:
https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/pull/5157

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).